# Which is the best method for filtering user selection in android development?

Tags: android, spinner

I wanted to know which is a best method for getting user input and then filtering that input. The only option i can think of is spinners. Basically I did is use spinners. In my case, I have one spinner with all states, and the second spinner with list of all colleges in those states. I filter the colleges accordingly to user selection for the state in the 1st spinner. I used spinners here, is their another way to do this. Thanks in advance, sorry If i was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in right direction. I am also doing same kind of project using two spinner.select the 1st spinner and based on the Item selected add items to 2nd spinner in

```
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //add items to array/arraylist of 2nd spinner

        }
```